# How do I find the maximum of this quantity?

Tags: maximum

I am looking for the maximum of the function

$$V(r^*)=\left( 1-\dfrac{2m}{r} \right)\left( \dfrac{l(l+1)}{r^2}-\dfrac{6m}{r^3} \right)$$

in the coordinate $r^*$ for given $l$ and $m$, where $r^*=r+2m \ln(r-2m)$.

How can I do it?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I am clueless, `FindMaximum` gives the maximum for the variabel `r` I do not know how to find the maximum in `r^*`

Comment: find the maximum in terms of $r$, and then plug that expression into $r^*$?

Comment: Please clarify the function definition!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have the potential `V` defined in terms of the coordinate `r', but I need the maximum of the potential in terms of the variable `r*` whch depends on `r`

Comment: @mattiav27 Ok that means the lefthand side of your function definition should be `V[r]` instead of `V[r*]` . With r defined implicitly in the constraint `r*=…[r]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes

Comment: @mattiav27 What is known about the parameters `l,m`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann $l$ is a non-negative integer and $m$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary condition to maximize is `D[V,r]/D[r*,r]` which can be solved analytically

```
sol=Solve[0 == D[(1 - 2 m/r) ((l (l + 1))/r^2 - (6 m)/r^3), r]/D[r + 2 m Log[r - 2 m], r], r]
(* {{r -> 2 m}, 
{r -> (9 m + 3 l m + 3 l^2 m - 
Sqrt[-96 (l + l^2) m^2 + (-9 m - 3 l m - 3 l^2 m)^2])/(2 (l + l^2))}, 
{r -> (9 m + 3 l m + 3 l^2 m + 
Sqrt[-96 (l + l^2) m^2 + (-9 m - 3 l m - 3 l^2 m)^2])/(2 (l + l^2))}}*)
```

Knowing the parameters `l,m` you might check the result to be a maximum!

Comment: ...i'm kinda confused. The function $V(z)$ clearly diverges (to $\infty$) at $z\to0^+$, so how can it have a maximum at all? Your solutions seem to be minima (or local maxima), not a global maximum!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It's only a necessary condition for an extremum. I didn't check for maximum! The influence of the constraint shoulden'd be disregared.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the constraint", but the function is unbounded from above for all $m,l$, so the problem has no solution...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The constraint (sorry for my wording) `r*=r+2Log[r-2m], m>0`  shows, that real `r*` only exist if `r>2m`. Thus the singularity `V[0+]` is excluded .

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense! (But do note that $r=2m$ is a boundary, so the maximum could in principle be located there. Strictly speaking, one should test that value too, together with the three you write in your answer).